# Windows 7 64 Bit Can't Get Past Format

Tags: windows-7, installation, power-management

favorite  Just assembled a new machine:

MSI 880GM-E41 motherboard

500GB Samsung hard drive

AMD Athlon II X4 640 processor

4GB RAM

Windows 7 64 Bit

LITE-ON Black 4X Blu-ray reader

I boot up, start the install. When it gets to the screen to select what partition, the motherboard loses power. It doesnt make sense, I can leave it in the bios settings for a very long time and it doesnt lose power. When it does lose power, the monitor shuts down and the mouse loses power, but the power light stays on. I cannot tell if it is a harware or software problem.